# Access to withFormat from a filter in Grails 2.5.5

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails for an API.

On a filter I define some checks before the request hits the controller, if those checks don't pass, an error should be returned.

The error is on XML or JSON format, depending on content negotiation. So I tried to use withFormat to render the error from the filter, but the filter doesn't have withFormat like a controller does.

Is there any way of getting the content negotiation on a filter?

In the meantime I did my own format guessing form the Accept header, but I would like to use the Grails withFormat in the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, [from the docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.5/guide/single.html#filterVariablesAndScopes)

> However, filters only support a subset of the methods available to
>   controllers and tag libraries. These include:
>
> redirect - For redirects to other controllers and actions
>
> render - For rendering custom responses

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. I've sent a feature request to support withFormat in filters.